# Rails break and return not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with koala. I have to check the permission given is granted by user for the application. I have made a helper called facebook helper. There is a `def has_permission?(perm)`. My code follows:

```
def has_permission? (perm)
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.token)
  @permissions = @graph.get_connections('me', 'permissions')
  @bool = false
  @permissions.each do |p|
   if p[0] == perm && p[1] == 'granted'
     @bool = true
     break
   end
  end
 return @bool
end
```

It always returns false. What is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it myself:**

```
def has_permission? (perm)
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.token)
  @permissions = @graph.get_connections('me', 'permissions')
  # binding.pry
  @bool = false
  @permissions.each do |p|
    if (p['permission'] == perm && p['status'] == 'granted')
      @bool = true
      break
    end
  end
  @bool
end
```

Just changed `p[0]` to `p['permission']` and `p[1]` to `p['status']`

Answer (score 1):

Is your @permissions getting populated? You can also write this without the `break`

```
def has_permission? (perm)
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.token)
  @permissions = @graph.get_connections('me', 'permissions')
  @bool = false
  @permissions.each do |p|
    unless @bool
      @bool = (p[0] == perm && p[1] == 'granted')
    end
  end
  @bool
end
```

I would also move the `p[0] == perm && p[1] == 'granted'` into its own method for better readability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to use unless in multiple line implementation.

Comment: `unless` is just another way of writing `if !` so you can do that. Either way, the value of  `@bool` depends on `(p['permission'] == perm && p['status'] == 'granted')` so it is better to assign that to `@bool` IMO.

Doing it that way also eliminates the use of `break`, so a little cleaner.